# Создание apk файла на colab.research.google.com

Tags: python, apk, google-colaboratory

Пытаюсь создать apk файл в colab.research.google.com, но выскакивает вот такая ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? И какой фрагмент кода прислать, чтобы разобраться в чем проблема? Не могу добавить текст ошибки, вложил его в файл https://cloud.mail.ru/public/vwyF/D9GeArxTL

Comment: Там написано, что ошибку возможно нужно искать в логе до этой команды. В этом куске лога только настройки окружения и команда запуска и всё.

Comment: Да, точно, ошибка сама вот так выглядит: ERROR: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался, нужно было просто обновить cython, так же установил libtool, возможно, это тоже помогло